# RDFa for videos rendered in javascript

Tags: javascript, rdfa

I am trying to add RDFa tags to videos so they can be indexed by Google and Yahoo. However the object and embed code for the videos are inserted by javascript, so they aren't actually in html. Can I put a duplicate object in a noscript tag? Is there another solution?

http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=162163

Answer (score 0):

RDFa markup generated by Javascript is invisible to Google and Yahoo, just like other markup.

The good news is that in RDFa, the *element* actually doesn't matter at all; it's all about the *attributes*. So you can just put all the RDFa markup on `<div>` or `<span>` elements without visible content, you don't need to use `<object>`. You can use RDFa's `resource=""` attribute instead of `href=""` on elements that don't support `href`.

At least that's what the RDFa spec says; I haven't verified wether Google and Yahoo actually process it that way.

Answer (score 0):

This might provide some help for the more general problem (HTML code inserted by JavaScript): [A proposal for making AJAX crawlable](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/10/proposal-for-making-ajax-crawlable.html)